# Search character type in int field mysql giving wrong results

Tags: mysql

When I done a search with character in int field, it gives results for which the int field has values as zero.

```
select * from table where b = "test"
```

column b is int type. Results obtained is rows for which b have value zero.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: How can you avoid this? Don't do that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this - mysql won't let you insert text into an int field in the first place.

Comment: Its because user try to search an integer field with character value for which validation is missing.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has this little quirk that `CAST('some text' AS INT)` yields zero.  It also happens that `CAST('123some text' AS INT)` yields `123`.

When you do `WHERE integer_valued_column = 'text'` your `'text'` is implicitly cast to an integer value. So that's what causes the strange behavior you've observed.

How do you avoid it? @Drew is right. Don't do it.

Comment: Is it okay if I change the query like this "select * from table where b = "test" and b!=0"  ?

Comment: You can do anything you want. But mixing integers and text isn't generally considered good IT practice.